# Dynamically change catalog name in jOOQ

Tags: database, dynamic, jooq, catalog

My database instance name is different between multiple environments - how can the catalog name in jOOQ be assigned dynamically?

There doesn't seem to dynamically assign the catalog name for the generated class extends CatalogImpl.

```
private MyDatabase() {
    super("DatabaseInstanceName");
}
```

Using jOOQ trial 3.8.3. Currently using SQLSERVER and H2 dialects. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code generation support for `Catalog` (which corresponds to SQL Server's database) was added to jOOQ in version 3.8 (issue [#2032](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2032)). Thus far, it is not yet possible to apply any mapping between catalogs. This feature is on the roadmap (probably for version 3.9):

- Runtime mapping ([issue #4793](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4793))
- Code generation mapping ([issue #4794](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4794))

Until then, you can turn off the rendering of catalog names in generated SQL by specifying [`Settings.renderCatalog`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#renderCatalog). More information about jOOQ's `Settings` can be found here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings

Comment: Cool. Thank you Lukas. Actually managed to discover this earlier today. Wooo! As well as initially overcoming it by specifying catalog name as blank string.

Comment: @Gil: Indeed, that blank string is a valid workaround, too. Thanks for the feedback! Glad it works for you now